# Как с помощью css и jquery можно реализовать элемент как на картинке?

Tags: jquery, css

[image: range element]

Как с помощью css и jquery можно реализовать элемент как на картинке?

Comment: Синяя полоска это абсолютно позиционированный элемент внутри родителя...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```css
*{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
ul{     
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  max-width: 800px;
  margin: 35px auto;  
  font-size: 0;
  font-family: 'Segoe UI', sans-serif;
  color: #999;  
  padding: 25px;
}
ul > li{
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;  
  position: relative;  
  font-size: 15px;
  width: 14.28%;  
}
ul > li:before{
  content: '';
  position: absolute; top: -15px; left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 10px;
  background: #609CEE;
}
ul > li:first-child:before{
  left: 50%; width: 50%; 
}
ul > li:after{
  content: '';
  position: absolute; top: -20px; left: 50%;
  width: 1px;
  height: 20px;
  background: #609CEE;
}
ul > li:nth-child(5):before{     
  background: rgb(96,156,238); /* Old browsers */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(96,156,238,1) 0%, rgba(96,156,238,1) 50%, rgba(204,204,204,1) 50%, rgba(204,204,204,1) 100%);
background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, rgba(96,156,238,1) 0%, rgba(96,156,238,1) 50%, rgba(204,204,204,1) 50%, rgba(204,204,204,1) 100%);
background: -o-linear-gradient(left, rgba(96,156,238,1) 0%, rgba(96,156,238,1) 50%, rgba(204,204,204,1) 50%, rgba(204,204,204,1) 100%);
background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(96,156,238,1) 0%, rgba(96,156,238,1) 50%, rgba(204,204,204,1) 50%, rgba(204,204,204,1) 100%); /* FF3.6-15 */ /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */ /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#609cee', endColorstr='#cccccc',GradientType=1 ); /* IE6-9 */
}
ul > li:nth-child(6):before,
ul > li:nth-child(7):before,
ul > li:nth-child(6):after,
ul > li:nth-child(7):after{
  background: #ccc;
}
ul > li:last-child:before{  
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><span>A1</span></li>
  <li><span>A2</span></li>
  <li><span>A2+</span></li>
  <li><span>B1</span></li>
  <li><span>B2</span></li>
  <li><span>C1</span></li>
  <li><span>C2</span></li>
</ul>
```